How do I find the y-intercepts of the vortex ring function, u(y')?
I am trying to graphically compute a vortex ring, $u(y')$ in an $x'-y'$ axis, whose vortex locations $d'$ and $-d'$ are distorted by some unknown function, $\pm y'(d')$, which are the $y-$intercepts of $u(y')$.
$$u(y')=\frac{1}{y'-d'}\left(1-e^{-\frac{\left(y'-d'\right)^{2}}{R^{2}}}\right)-\frac{1}{y'+d'}\left(1-e^{-\frac{\left(y'+d'\right)^{2}}{R^{2}}}\right)$$
Which we set $u(y')=0$ and solve for $y'$.
$$\frac{1}{y'-d'}\left(1-e^{-\frac{\left(y'-d'\right)^{2}}{R^{2}}}\right)=\frac{1}{y'+d'}\left(1-e^{-\frac{\left(y'+d'\right)^{2}}{R^{2}}}\right)$$
$R$ is a constant that represents vortex radius (though actual radius is mysteriously closer to $R\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{5}}$ ).

The orange lines show the exact solutions to $u(y')$ as ${\color{Orange} y'(d')}$, the red dots show the values of ${\color{Red}\pm d)}$, and the green dots are my estimated solutions; $${\color{Green} y'(d')=\pm\sqrt{\left(R\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{5}}\right)^{2}+d^{2}}}$$
